# How to add button to open a hyperlink in a form - PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven

How to add button to a form in PowerApps. Clicking the button should navigate to the hyperlink provided.

Comment: Canvas powerapps is different from Model driven powerapps.. which one youre using ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a text box called "TextInput1" and a button called "Button1".

On the button's "Select" event you would put

```
Launch(TextInput1.Text);
```

If you would rather close the PowerApp and redirect to a different URL you would do this...

```
Exit(Launch("https://google.com"));
```

Or this if you want to pull the location from the text box...

```
Exit(Launch(TextInput1.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you Jason :) But the above command opens up the url in new tab so can you please tell me how can we redirect to open it in the same tab...

Comment: Expanded my answer to show how to do the closes thing.